# Using boto3 and python to call describe_data_set for AWS quicksight throws InvalidParameterValueException but I'm passing a string

Tags: python, boto3

It throws this error

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the DescribeDataSet operation: The data set type is not supported through API yet.

If I create a string and assign it the value of a valid ID it works just fine?

```
import boto3
import json
import pandas as pd

acount_id = 'your account'

qs_client = boto3.client('quicksight', region_name='us-east-1')

# LIST ALL DATA SETS
response = qs_client.list_data_sets(
    AwsAccountId = acount_id,
    MaxResults = 100
)
results = response['DataSetSummaries']

while "NextToken" in response:
    response = qs_client.list_data_sets(
        AwsAccountId = acount_id,
        MaxResults = 100,
        NextToken=response["NextToken"]
    )
    results.extend(response["DataSetSummaries"])

for i in results:

    print(i['DataSetId'])
    response = qs_client.describe_data_set(
            AwsAccountId=acount_id,
            DataSetId=i['DataSetId']
    )

    print(response)
```

[image]

Comment: Is that actual, full error message? There is nothing else, even a line number?

Comment: If I run your code it succeeds. In your last for loop, try checking the type to see if you have any values that aren't strings (<class 'str>)' by adding in this line: print(type(i['DataSetId']))

Comment: It is indeed a type of str, that is what is baffling

Comment: Certainly drop some more print statements into that final for loop to see which values are succeeding vs failing. How many data sets do you have in the account?

Comment: @ChrisLindseth Thanks for that, there are some values that fail when pasted in as well. So, I need to analyze what about the dataset it doesn't like.

Comment: Update the code below to show which data set type isn't supported by the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few minor changes to your code. I think there may have been an issue with the NextToken logic - I believe you would need to use response.keys() as shown below. The following code works for me and yields the results as shown below.

```
import boto3
import json

account_id = '0123456789'

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
qs_client = session.client('quicksight')

# LIST ALL DATA SETS
response = qs_client.list_data_sets(AwsAccountId = account_id,MaxResults = 100)
results = response['DataSetSummaries']

while "NextToken" in response.keys():
    response = qs_client.list_data_sets(AwsAccountId = account_id,MaxResults = 100,NextToken=response["NextToken"])
    results.extend(response["DataSetSummaries"])
for i in results:
    x = i['DataSetId']
    try:
        response = qs_client.describe_data_set(AwsAccountId=account_id,DataSetId=x)
        print("succeeded loading: {} for data set {} ".format(x, response['DataSet']['Name']))
    except:
        print("failed loading: {}  ".format(x))
```

Outputs the following default Quicksight dataset names:

Web and Social Media Analytics
Sales Pipeline
Business Review
People Overview

Comment: It still is throwing the error hmm was going to attach a picture